# dt.date returns AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

All the values in the columns that I'm trying to use pd.to_datetime() on look like for example, 2017-10-02 10:56:33

So I ran the code below

```
order_time['order_purchase_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(order_time['order_purchase_timestamp'], errors='coerce')
order_time['order_develiered_customer_date'] = pd.to_datetime(order_time['order_delivered_customer_date'], errors='coerce')
```

then I tried to do

```
order_time['date_order'] = order_time['order_purchase_timestamp'].dt.date
order_time['date_delivered'] = order_time['order_delivered_customer_date'].dt.date
```

which returns the "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

I checked the dtype and they were

```
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

I can't figure what the problem is here.

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: We need reproducible code, please

Comment: I made a new dataframe that only consists of order dates and delivery dates that look identical with different values and review scores which are just numbers from 1 to 5. There are 100000 rows x 4 columns.

Comment: Could you add the first few lines (5 or 10) from this dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal?
Are you looking for this?

```
order_time['date_order'] = order_time['order_purchase_timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

[Python's strftime directives](https://strftime.org/)

Comment: My goal is getting how many days it took for delivery so I was trying to get only the dates first.

Comment: I guess you have a problem with your data or some code above. Please note that you still need to apply the "order_time['order_purchase_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(order_time['order_purchase_timestamp'], errors='coerce')" before this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should work, I replicated your example:

df:

```
order_purchase_timestamp
2017-10-02 10:56:33
2017-10-02 10:56:33
2017-10-02 10:56:33
123
2017-10-02 10:56:33
```

Code:

```
df['order_purchase_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_purchase_timestamp'], errors='coerce')
df['date_order'] = df['order_purchase_timestamp'].dt.date
print(df)


  order_purchase_timestamp  date_order
0      2017-10-02 10:56:33  2017-10-02
1      2017-10-02 10:56:33  2017-10-02
2      2017-10-02 10:56:33  2017-10-02
3                      NaT         NaT
4      2017-10-02 10:56:33  2017-10-02
```

There's something wrong with the data, if you can paste a sample it would help.